# Acrescentar uma Label em um Formulário HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, estava precisando de uma ajuda para acrescentar uma label em um "mini" formulário HTML. Preciso de uma label, como por exemplo : First Name e colocar junto desse form aqui, na mesma linha, e quando clicar no botão `show selected` disparar um `alert` com o valor do campo First Name, Country e State. O formulário é esse aqui :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
var citiesByState = {
Australia: ["Sidney","Camberra"],
Canada: ["Toronto","Montreal"],
USA: ["Chicago","Miami"]
}
function makeSubmenu(value) {
if(value.length==0) document.getElementById("citySelect").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
else {
var citiesOptions = "";
for(cityId in citiesByState[value]) {
citiesOptions+="<option>"+citiesByState[value][cityId]+"</option>";
}
document.getElementById("citySelect").innerHTML = citiesOptions;
}
}
function displaySelected() { var country = document.getElementById("countrySelect").value;
var city = document.getElementById("citySelect").value;
alert(country+"\n"+city);
}
function resetSelection() {
document.getElementById("countrySelect").selectedIndex = 0;
document.getElementById("citySelect").selectedIndex = 0;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="resetSelection()">
<select id="countrySelect" size="1" onchange="makeSubmenu(this.value)">
<option value="" disabled selected>Choose State</option>
<option>Australia</option>
<option>Canada</option>
<option>USA</option>
</select>
<select id="citySelect" size="1" >
<option value="" disabled selected>Choose City</option>
<option></option>
</select>
<button onclick="displaySelected()">show selected</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Desde já agradeço

Comment: Valeu Leo, brigadão

Answer (score 0):

Em primeiro lugar coloque um campo no HTML, exemplo

`<input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name">`

Na `function displaySelected()` recupere o valor digitado

```
var firstName=document.getElementById("firstName").value;
```

Caso nada seja digitado pode colocar um valor default

```
if (firstName==""){
    firstName = "Nameless";
}
```

Ainda na `function displaySelected()` altere a forma de apresentar o alert, caso o State não seja selecionado o alerta irá lembrar de fazer isso

```
if (country){
   alert(firstName+ "\n"+country+"\n"+city);
}else{
   alert("Choose State");
}
```

A `function resetSelection()` também teve alterações bem óbvias

Modificado

```
document.getElementById("citySelect").innerHTML = '<option value="" disabled selected>Choose City</option>';
```

Incluído

```
document.getElementById("firstName").value="";
```

No HTML acrescentado botão para disparar a função `resetSelection()`

```js
var citiesByState = {
Australia: ["Sidney","Camberra"],
Canada: ["Toronto","Montreal"],
USA: ["Chicago","Miami"]
}
function makeSubmenu(value) {
if(value.length==0) document.getElementById("citySelect").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
else {
var citiesOptions = "";
for(cityId in citiesByState[value]) {
citiesOptions+="<option>"+citiesByState[value][cityId]+"</option>";
}
document.getElementById("citySelect").innerHTML = citiesOptions;
}
}
function displaySelected() { 
var firstName=document.getElementById("firstName").value;
if (firstName==""){
firstName = "Nameless";
}
var country = document.getElementById("countrySelect").value;
var city = document.getElementById("citySelect").value;
if (country){
alert(firstName+ "\n"+country+"\n"+city);
}else{
alert("Choose State");
}
}
function resetSelection() {
document.getElementById("countrySelect").selectedIndex = 0;
document.getElementById("citySelect").innerHTML = '<option value="" disabled selected>Choose City</option>';
document.getElementById("firstName").value="";
}
```

```html
<body onload="resetSelection()">
<input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
<select id="countrySelect" size="1" onchange="makeSubmenu(this.value)">
<option value="" disabled selected>Choose State</option>
<option>Australia</option>
<option>Canada</option>
<option>USA</option>
</select>
<select id="citySelect" size="1" >
<option value="" disabled selected>Choose City</option>
<option></option>
</select>
<button onclick="displaySelected()">show selected</button>
<button onclick="resetSelection()">Reset selected</button>
```